# visual studio c++ won't access files with a 3 letter extension

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

visual studio 2013 windows 7.

```
std::string filename1 = "hold.a";
std::ofstream filex(filename1, std::ios::binary);
filex << " Hello" << std::endl;
filex.close();
```

works just fine

```
std::string filename1 = "hold.txt";
std::ofstream filex(filename1, std::ios::binary);
filex << " Hello" << std::endl;
filex.close();
```

gives me a permission denied error on file creation. The only difference is the three letter extension on the output file.

Ifstream and fopen behave the same way.

Comment: Maybe `hold.txt` already exists in the current directory and is used?

Comment: And how did you check? Did you also try with something like `foo.txt`?

Comment: My advice is to turn off "Hide extensions for known types" in explorer.

Comment: I tried several file names verifying with windows explorer that they did (or didn't) exist.  Using ifstream to check that a file does exist on a file that does exist will produce a permission denied error if the file has a three letter extension and will work exactly how it is supposed to if the file has a single letter extension, a two letter extension and a four letter extension.

Comment: There is no such check on the number of letters of an extension. What you are describing is very unusual behavior from your system. Try disabling your antivirus software.

Comment: Hide extensions is not on, but I agree that it's likely something like that.

Comment: I agree that the behavior is very odd.

Comment: Is this a minimal program or part of a larger program? If this is part of a larger program have you tested a minimal program. I ask because this kind of thing can be caused by Undefined Behavior.

Comment: jpg and txt produce this behavior. the extension zzz does not. It's got to be some windows thing. The snippet above is compiled alone.

Comment: I reiterate my disable the antivirus comment. A malfunctioning AV could cause this.

Comment: I'm on a machine with rather restricted access. To turn off the av may take me some time, but I will work on that.

Comment: Try your program on a different computer.

Comment: Are you showing hidden and system files? In CMD you can use `dir /a`. Hidden and system files can only be overwritten if the hidden/system attribute is preserved via `CreateFile`. Otherwise you can open the existing file for writing and truncate it.

Comment: program works fine on another machine. Hidden and system files are shown.

Comment: Run error checking, example `if (filex.bad()) {DWORD e = GetLastError(); cout << e;}`

Answer (score 1):

Your both code works fine for me but You also can use Win32 API, Just include `Windows.h` and:

```
HANDLE hFile;
char DataBuffer[] = "This is some test data to write to the file.";

hFile = CreateFile("foo.txt", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

WriteFile(hFile, DataBuffer, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

Run the program As Administrator, btw (If you have admin access).

Comment: with #include <windows.h> at the front of your code via cut and paste, my compiler does not like hFile = Createfile..... and WriteFile. The long list of attributes and all of the lines look the same as yours to my eye.

Comment: @dfs Your text is not so clear to me. What is the problem right now?

Comment: my apologies. The error was here. Your code does compile and run. foo.txt does not appear where I believe it should appear. If I modify the name to foo.tx, it appears exactly where I think it should go. The more I investigate this, the more I think it's a local windows configuration issue. I ran a version of this at home last night and it worked exactly as I thought it should. Today it has failed in the same way on two machine. I'll ask another coder to run it and see what he gets before I talk to the local it folk.

Comment: Don't ignore a return value of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. Print the `GetLastError()` Windows error code. It may also help to print the last kernel status code from `RtlGetLastNtStatus`. There's no public import lib for ntdll.dll in the SDK, but you can get this function dynamically, e.g. `NTSTATUS (NTAPI *RtlGetLastNtStatus)() = NULL;` `(FARPROC)RtlGetLastNtStatus = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll"), "RtlGetLastNtStatus")`.

Comment: Error handlers tell me that I don't have permission to open a file with three letters in the extension. If I alter the code (and if I'm reading...the filename) to 1,2 or 4 letter extensions. It works fine. The code works on my home computer, but not on machines at work. I'm working with IT to remove the antivirus on a temporary basis.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped me cover ground on this. The actual answer was the IT department had mucked with permissions and the machine needed to be reimaged.